# Activity started from Service is calling the onPause too soon

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I'm starting an activity that plays form the MediaPlayer from a service and it starts fine but immediately calls the onPause and leaves. But if I don't put an onPause() method in the Activity... the Mediaplayer plays fine and the view is correct. Below is my code:

Service:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class ReminderService extends WakeReminderIntentService {

    public ReminderService() {
        super("ReminderService");
            }

    @Override
    void doReminderWork(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("ReminderService", "Doing work.");
        Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), TestRec.class);
        dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);


    }
}
```

TestRec.class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class TestRec extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer mp;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
         getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED

                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD

                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON

                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                 );

         mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
            mp.start();
    }



    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        mp.stop();
                finish();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onPause() is called not by activity, but by android itself, to indicate that activity has lost focus, and other activity has it now. What activity comes in front instead?